# команда завершения RDP сеанса

Tags: python

Подскажите команду или модуль для завершения определенного RDP сеанса на Python

Comment: А как вы присоединяетесь через rdp?

Comment: @nick-gabpe стандартной утилитой винды подключение к удаленному рабочему столу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это завершит все сеансы Microsoft remote desktop

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /f /im mstsc.exe")
```

флаг `/f` значит `force`, без подтверждения от пользователя.

Comment: а если я с сервера хочу завершить определенный сеанс определенного пользователя? например user1?

Comment: еще вопрос, в код os.system(" ") можно использовать любую консольную команду? например от diskpart?

Comment: `taskkill /F /IM mstsc.exe /FI "USERNAME eq user1"`

да, любые консольные команды

Comment: это будет завершение сеанса или просто отключение?

Comment: А в чем разница? Это просто остановка процесса.